# PHP MYSQL PDO SUM of columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to php and I've searched for the past hour and read all the documentation I could find and nothing is helping. I have a table that has a bunch of rows of data. I'm trying to pick one column from the whole table and add them all together. Here is what I got. All this tells me is how many rows there are that match my query, not the total sum of column I want. Any help is appreciated.

```
$res1 = $db->prepare('SELECT sum(distance) FROM trip_logs WHERE user_id = '. $user_id .' AND status = "2"');
$res1->execute();
$sum_miles = 0;
while($row1 = $res1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$sum_miles += $row1['distance'];
}
echo $sum_miles;
```

Comment: Put the whole SQL string in `"` and wrap `'` around the field values. SQL usually uses `'` on the inside not `"`.

Comment: @developerwjk mysql can use both, and I'm pretty sure all sql servers can do so. This has nothing to do with the problem which is the lack of understanding of [aggregating functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). OP needs to `GROUP BY` something if she wants the `SUM()` to be able to... sum... the different values

Comment: Add an alias `sum(distance) as distance`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Why should there be a GROUP BY? I've done this type of query many times without it. If that was your reason to downvote Jay's answer (if it was you), then you're wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and those query you had did work because mysql groups rows automatically if you don't

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, Actually on MSSQL 2000 if you put values in `"` rather than `'` it tries to treat them as fieldnames...but that's a pretty old server.

Comment: Maybe we all just need a `GROUP` hug.

Comment: Alright, so I just tried everyone's advice and it still displaying row totals... not the sum of the column. :/ I don't get it... ugh

Comment: @developerwjk you got me :p

Comment: @JayBlanchard I can't help but smile with your group hug comment. please have a great day, sir.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're only returning one row in this instance. Modify your summed column to have an alias:

```
SELECT SUM(distance) AS totDistance FROM trip_logs ....
```

Now you can can fetch the row -

```
$row = $res1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['totDistance'];
```

No need to loop.

Comment: The OP is only selecting one user, so there is no need to group.

Comment: there is no need to group because mysql will do it itself. [If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - You do not need group bys for SUM - See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22bea/1

Comment: @Scopey that is true because mysql will do as if you group all rows. see my comment

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your point @FélixGagnon-Grenier. first you say there has to be a `GROUP BY`, now you're arguing that it isn't needed? Or are you saying there is *never* a need to use `GROUP` with `SUM` in MySQL?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I mean that we are both right. You are right because you can use `SUM()` without grouping, and I'm right because when you do so it only means Mysql will GROUP BY for you. thanks for following up

Comment: I think I just got it to work, Jay. Give me 5 mins to make sure it works :)

Comment: I'm starting to think that `$sum_miles = 0;` and `$sum_miles += $row1['distance'];` may play a role here. @JayBlanchard Lordie, I even put in an answer not long ago related to a similar question.

Comment: That's why the OP should sum in the query @Fred-ii-. Totaling in a loop like that should be reserved for cases where the math requires other, external, variables.

Comment: So, this code works just fine... the problem was the column had the distance in with the commas: 1,240 instead of 1240, so when I thought it was adding the rows together, it was just adding the 1 before the comma.... I feel stupid. Thanls everyone. Long time searcher, first time poster. YOU GUYS ROCK!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I guess it's always a good thing to ask what type of data is in the given row(s). commas *face palm*. Glad this was solved.

Comment: [Seems I was right from the get-go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332539/php-mysql-pdo-sum-of-columns#comment45012275_28332539) - wink.

Comment: Haha, totally annoyed that I didn't realize the commas were in there. There goes two hours of work for a darn comma. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: @JustinAustin Don't feel so bad. I think there's a valuable lesson that can be taken and learned from this and is for us to have first asked and should always be asked, as to what the data is a table and in what format, so that we know what we're dealing with, so that everyone's on the same level plain. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM()` without explicitely grouping your rows because [if you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

If however you want to use the `SUM()` function for something slightly more complicated you have to group your rows so that the sum can operate on what you want.

If you want to get multiple sums in a single statement, for example to get the distance for all users at once, you need to group the rows explicitely:

```
$res1 = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        SUM(distance) AS distance,
        user_id
    FROM trip_logs WHERE status = '2'
    GROUP BY user_id
");
$res1->execute();
while ($row = $res1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "user $row[user_id] has runned $row[distance] km.\n";
}
```

This will return the sum of distances *by user*, not for all users at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using a Class :

```
    class Sample_class{

        private $db;

        public function __construct($database) {
            $this->db = $database;
        }   

        public function GetDistant($user_id,$status) {

                    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT sum(distance) FROM trip_logs WHERE user_id =? AND status =?");

                    $query->bindValue(1, $user_id);
                    $query->bindValue(2, $status);

                    try{ $query->execute();     

                     $rows =  $query->fetch();
                     return $rows[0];

              } catch (PDOException $e){die($e->getMessage());}  
            } 
    }

$dist = new Sample_class($db);

$user_id = 10;
$status = 2;

echo $dist->GetDistant($user_id,$status);
```